# Convert varchar2 to date function in View

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column in view thats has literals as '26Jul2022 10:05:52:209' and has datatype as varchar2. I need to convert this column datatype into Date. How can I do that?

Comment: The logic for this column as below.

substr(to_char(m_column, 'ddMonyyyy HH:MI:SS:ff'),0, length(to_char(m_column, 'ddMonyyyy HH:MI:SS:ff')) - 3) as date2


The datatype of m_column is timestamp. When I use this logic, it convert the column into varchar2. I want Date datatype instead. I hope it clarify my question.

Comment: And the issue is ...? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's `date` datatype doesn't store milliseconds, but you could use the `timestamp` datatype instead by calling `to_timestamp`:

```sql
SELECT *, TO_TIMESTAMP(some_column, 'DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3')
FROM   some_table
```

Comment: The output of above is '26-JUL-22 10.05.52.209000000 AM'. Can I change it into '26JUL2022 10.05.52.209000000 AM'?

Comment: @Mohsin ALvi: Do you mean you have a tool that displays the timestamp thus? Does your tool have settings how to display timestamps? Then change the setting.